# Does Android support the OpenYmsg API?

Tags: android

Does Android support the OpenYmsg API?

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK itself does not support the Yahoo messenger protocol - but it's no problem to add external Java libs. So have fun. :-)

Comment: I have included external java libs.but when i run the program it shows following error...                      
09-21 16:21:17.883: ERROR/InputThread(262): error on process packet
09-21 16:21:17.883: ERROR/InputThread(262): org.openymsg.network.LoginRefusedException: Login Failed, Login url: https://login.yahoo.com/config/pwtoken_get?src=ymsgr&ts=&login=login failed&passwd=kalasikarthi&chal=s%26c-a-v*t%26b%25o%26%28y-p%25t-p%29-%28l%258-x%25n-e%25y-m%25j-u%25l-%285%253-y%25e%29%29 return code: -1

Comment: Then you have to figure out what the error means. Maybe you should build a real Java program first to test the library. I don't think that this is related only to Android. Oh, and _do not_ include critical information like passwords on stackoverflow!